# Changing constants in the source file, do i need to re-make the library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

If i make a change in the value of constant in one of the files in the source code, do i have to re-make and re-install the library again? Or will the library just use the changed value?

Comment: C++ is a *compiled* language. Changing a source file will not automatically update an already compiled executable or library. The sequence of steps to make a change is: 1) Make modification in source; 2) Compile source into object file; 3) Link all object files into executable/library; 4) Repeat as needed.

Comment: hey thanks for the info, i was thinking the same but i thought as i was not doing big change, just changing the coefficient, the compiled library might have still link to the source code and this might not change much. but now i am recompiling the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You will have to re compile and link the code that has your constant to the rest of the object files, if any.

If you want to avoid having to recompile code like this again and again, consider putting the value of the constant in an environment variable or in a configuration file and then bootstrapping the value of the constant from there

Answer (score 0):

Source code is as it's name implies the source that the compiler uses to generate code. Once the code is generated there is no connection between the source code and the generated code. Therefore you must recompile/rebuild to make changes take effect.